# How can I initialize a variable in Android class?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem when I initialize my LOC or LAT variables, app crashes, where is the problem?

```
public final class MyLocationListener  implements LocationListener {

Context c;
Camera mycam =Camera.open(1);
Float[] LOC;
Float[] LAT;


public MyLocationListener(Context context) {
     c= context;

     // read all file & spiting them

     String DataPoints = read_db("gpspoints");
     DataPoints.trim();
     String []ar=DataPoints.split("&");

     String[] twovar=ar[2].split("/");
     this.LOC[1]=(float) 1;
     this.LAT[1]=(float) 1;

     //end of read and Split
}
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. It should be `DataPoints = DataPoints.trim();`

Comment: Don't let us guess what the error is. Post your logcat.

Comment: why don't people post the error message?  Mind boggling.

Comment: curious why you aren't using index 0 for your LAT and LOC?

Comment: whats Exception on Log data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
this.LAT = new Float[2];
this.LOC = new Float[2];
```

Before

```
this.LOC[1]= (float) 1;
this.LAT[1]= (float) 1;
```

The problem is you wanna set a value in an array, but you have not initialised the array.

Comment: The problem is you wanna set a value in an array, but you have not initialised the array.

Comment: @user3185049 we have to use `2`, because the array index starts at `0` and you want to set the value of the index `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.LOC[0]=(float) 1;
this.LAT[0]=(float) 1;
```